# Excel Sum that excludes duplicates

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I have data in the following format:

```
Id    Value
------------
1     20
2     40
3     20
3     20
4     50
```

I want to sum the value column while excluding duplicates from the id column.  In this case, I should end up with a total of 130. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new column with duplicates removed; SUM() the new column.

Use the [COUNTIF](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP052090291033.aspx)() function to reduce values for duplicate ID's to 0 in the new column like this:

`=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)=1,B1,"")`

(example above assumes ID's are stored in column A, and their values are stored in column B)

[source and more detailed info](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ListFunctions.aspx)

Comment: Thanks.  This will get me where I need to be.  I had hoped that I could create a function that sums the data in place, without the addition of a new column, but this will do.

For future reference, I did have to make a slight modification to your function:

=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)=1,B1,"")

Comment: @Todd: You can hide the new column, but still get the sum of the hidden column.

Answer (score 2):

From Microsoft: [Filter for unique values or remove duplicate values](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP100739431033.aspx)

> - To filter for unique values, use the    **Advanced** command in the **Sort &
>     Filter**    group on the **Data** tab.
> - To remove    duplicate values, use the **Remove    Duplicates** command in
>     the **Data Tools**    group on the **Data**
>     tab.
> - To highlight    unique or duplicate values, use the    **Conditional
>     Formatting** command in the    **Style**
>     group on the **Home** tab.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to modify or hide the existing data.  Highlighting gets me nowhere when it comes to calculating a sum either.